# Ruby: Array in Hash table disappears

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an Array of elements (`temp`) that I place in a Hash (`user_followings`) like this:

```
user_followings[user.id] = temp
```

When I do `temp.clear` after the array are added to the Hash, the elements in the Hash table, also disappears.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the assignment, `user_followings[user.id]` **references** to the same `Array` object as `temp`, if you modify the content of one(e.g, `temp.clear`), the other is modified as well.

If this is not what you want, try

```
user_followings[user.id] = temp.dup
```